# jquery sidebar refresh too excessive?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 sidebars on my site, and due to the nature of the site (its a game script/site) certain parts of these need to be refreshed often- every 10 secs or so.

On the left sidebar theres a MAIL link and an ALERTS link, both of which flash if you have new content in either.

On the right sidebar, it has your stats, health, etc.

To do this I botched together some jquery thing. Eg for the left sidebar I have this code in the `head` tag of my main page.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#leftbar").load("leftbar.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#leftbar").load('leftbar.php?randval='+ Math.random());
      }, 9000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   });
</script>
```

Then in the sidebar i have a `<div id="leftbar"></div>` tag, which refreshes it every 10 secs. I have the same for the right sidebar.

My issue is, in my leftbar.php its set up like a normal page. At the top it connects to the database, queries the tables, then outputs the html depending on if theres new content. Then closing the db connection again.

Is this how its done? 
It seems excessive having to open and close the db connection every 10 seconds.

NOTE: I know nothing about javascript/jquery

Comment: not sure I understand your concern. The 10 second is something you defined. Are you worried about the DB usage, or network traffic or what?

Comment: DB usage really. My site's just running a little slow and I'm trying to pinpoint why. I'm  not that experienced in PHP/SQL so was just checking whether I'm doing things the normal way.

Comment: I'd check the queries to see if they're using the indexes first, a badly formed SQL query or badly indexed tables would be 99.99% of the times the culprit of things being slow  (and something you wouldn't notice when programming since usually you test with a few rows, but then in production when things get loaded with data day after day, is when you notice the problems of missing indexes, etc)

Comment: in 99% cases, the "slow" part is due to slow queries. Make sure you use prepared statements, and that your indexes are correct and well used.

Comment: im not too familiar with all the terms like 'prepared statements' and the importance of indexes etc, but all a part of learning aye. What would you refer to as a slow query?

Comment: it is a **huge** subject, and not the topic of the question. In  short: any query that returns one row shall be accessed through primary key/index. (check explain_plan). When you have to query one row many times, it can be faster to get them all (or a range of rows) and loop them in php/java (can be faster than a join) (with/without memcache). For range of rows (where x >= y), it depends. When the query is complex (some are several pages long), a combination of tricks and wizardries is needed. **tl; dr**. It all depends of the query, the data and the database engine, and setting, and oh, boy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is normal.

For some ajax auto-completion plugins, a db connection is made each keystroke, which can happen several times per second. Connection is not "costly" in mysql, and most db. I have to admit I was surprised too when I discovered that several years ago, coming from oracle.

Point is, an ajax request is a complete http request, with header and all. You could keep a connection open for the user session, but it will cost nearly as much as closing and opening a new one. And some stray connections can accumulate and blotch the db.

Answer (score 0):

That's typically how it's done, although normally you shouldn't have to manually close the connection every time. Usually it's smart enough to open and close itself when it's done requesting data. [See these docs for `mysql_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php) for a little more info/better explanation.

Comment: Oh right. so the mysql_close at the bottom of my leftbar.php is worth removing?

Answer (score 0):

hm ... good question, I'm curious if there is any best practices for this.

In my opinion you should read some articles about the noSQL technologies :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you've bitten off quite the morsel for you intro to jQuery/JavaScript! :)

It looks like your example should meet your needs. The database connections shouldn't be a worry as your are presumably using Apache? In that case, anything Apache can handle (a few thousand requests a second) should be fine.

You could also look into [push technology (long polling)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) to tell you when updates are available, instead of conducting a regular poll. Of course, this can bring apache to its knees.

So there are some great libs to offload this kind of work to like [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) and [ape](http://www.ape-project.org/), which can do [some sophisticated things](http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/) with polling and very small footprints : )